# SQL IFF function duplicating results?

Tags: sql-server

everyone.

I've a SQL query that is stumping me considerably.  Basically the query is being used to generate a report on the usage of product over acres of land and I am having two issues in particular.  I want to say that I spent some time trying to find examples or other people reporting the same problems online, but the hardest part for me was trying to put the issues into words...

Firstly, the query:

```
SELECT [GWPA].[FIELD #]
         ,[GWPA].Variety
         ,[GWPA].ProductID
         ,[GWPA].[Product Name]
         ,[GWPA].AppDate
         ,[GWPA].AppTime
         ,[GWPA].OperatorID
         ,[GWPA].[Units Applied]
         ,[GWPA].[Unit Type]
         ,[GWPA].Acres
         ,[GWPA].CropYear
         ,[GWPA].[Unit Price]
         --,SUM([HVFL].[Gross Weights])/100 AS GrossAsYieldPerField
         ,IIF([Load Type]='Gross Field',Sum([Gross Weights])/100,0) AS TotalAs
         ,IIF([Load Type]='B-Size',Sum([Gross Weights])/100,0) AS TotalBs

         ,(
         SELECT SUM([HVHV].Acres)

              FROM [PDOX].[harvest].[HARVEST] AS [HVHV]

              WHERE [HVHV].CYear = '2015'
         )
         AS TotalAcres

FROM [PDOX].[harvest].[FLDLOAD] [HVFL]
       INNER JOIN PDOX.growing.PESTAPPL AS [GWPA] ON [HVFL].[Field #] = [GWPA].[Field #]

WHERE [HVFL].CYear = '2015'

GROUP BY [GWPA].[FIELD #]
         ,[GWPA].Variety
         ,[GWPA].ProductID
         ,[GWPA].[Product Name]
         ,[GWPA].AppDate
         ,[GWPA].AppTime
         ,[GWPA].OperatorID
         ,[GWPA].[Units Applied]
         ,[GWPA].[Unit Type]
         ,[GWPA].Acres
         ,[GWPA].CropYear
         ,[GWPA].[Unit Price]
         ,[Load Type]
```

A sample of the results look like this:

FIELD # | Variety | ProductID | Product Name | AppDate | OperatorID | Units Applied | Unit Type | Acres | CropYear | Unit Price | TotalAs | TotalBs | TotalAcres

C-03 | 2137S | VINE-01-104 | Vine Extender | 7/25/2013 12:00:00 AM | Reabe | 42.5 | GAL. | 85 | 2013 | 9.54 | **48730** | **0** | **7368**

C-05 | 1833S | 0000-00-100 | Spraying Airplane | 6/9/1999 12:00:00 AM | Reabe | 62 | ACRE | 62 | 1999 | 4.05 | **0** | **60** | **7368**

C-05 | 1833S | 0000-00-100 | Spraying Airplane | 6/9/1999 12:00:00 AM | Reabe | 62 | ACRE | 62 | 1999 | 4.05 | **36141** | **0** | **7368**

I apologize for the less than stellar formatting, but I bolded the important parts in the to hopefully help.

1. So firstly, record #2 and record #3 should be a single row in the result set, I'd like to see the 36141 from the third result moved up to the 0 spot in the second result for the TotalAs field.  I'm not sure why the IFF functions seem to be separating these out into individual rows, but hopefully someone with more SQL knowledge can figure this out at a quick glance.
2. Secondly, the TotalAcres (last column) is the same in all three records.  I am not sure why the subquery seems to only be giving the result for the first FIELD # and posting it in all records, but if I take the query out and run it on its own with an additional where clause (AND) and specify a FIELD #, I actually get the correct TotalAcres as the result of running the query.

I would appreciate any insight that anyone could offer me on these two issues.  I'll be investigating the issue some more on my end and posting my findings should I come up with something before someone else does.

Thanks so much for your time :)

Comment: How could #2 and #3 be a single row when you `group by [Load Type]`?

Comment: Apparently all I was missing for the second issue was adding: **AND [HVHV].[FIELD #] = [GWPA].[FIELD #]** to my subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using `IIF` as an agregate, which also forces you to group by `[Load Type]` - something you apparently don't actually want.

The solution is actually quite simple - you can still use `case` in an aggregate function, so you can remove `[Load Type]` from the group by, and use something like this to get the sums:

```
sum(case when [LoadType] = 'Gross Field' then [Gross Weights] else 0 end) / 100 as TotalAs,
sum(case when [LoadType] = 'B-Size' then [Gross Weights] else 0 end) / 100 as TotalBs,
```

Comment: Perfect--I've actually never used IFF before, so I wasn't sure what to expect out of it, this query was handed to me by someone else to "fix it", so...  Thank you for providing a very easy solution to my first issue with this query!